# Excel VBA - Match function error (Unable to get match property)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a match search to filter out rows where certain data is matched. For example, I have "ButtonName" which shows which column filter has to be put and "`DataRange.Rows(1)`" is the range on which it tries to search for the match. Sometimes when I do some editing, it shows:

> object defined error

And now it is showing:

> Unable to get the match property

Please somebody tell me what is the error in the code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim myButton As OptionButton
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ButtonName As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myField As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim mySearch1, mySearch2, mySearch3 As Variant

    'Load Sheet into A Variable
      Set sht = ActiveSheet
      Set a = ActiveSheet
    'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
      On Error Resume Next
      sht.ShowAllData
      On Error GoTo 0

    'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
       Set DataRange = sht.Range("A13:AL3000") 'Cell Range

    'Retrieve User's Search Input

    mySearch1 = sht.Range("D4").Text 'Control Form     ''Contains data entered in D4cell

     ButtonName = sht.Range("M12").Text     

     If Not IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0))          Then

        myField = WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
     Else
       MsgBox "no match is found in range(" & rngToSearch.Address & ")."
     End If


    'Filter Data
       DataRange.AutoFilter _
       Field:=myField, _
       Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch1 & "*", _
       Operator:=xlAnd, _
       Criteria2:="=*" & mySearch2 & "*", _
       Operator:=xlAnd, _
       Criteria2:="=*" & mySearch3 & "*", _
       Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

The Error occurs on this line:

```
If Not IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0))
```

Comment: Take a moment to familarise yourself with [SO] and the syntax's you can use to highlight your question. I am afraid this question lacks any view of the spreadsheet, so we're left in the dark on what the data looks like. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jeremy,   I am new to stack overflow so may be i may not be able to convey the error that i am facing..   Actually i am getting error on WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1),0))  line which shows "Unable to get match property"..

Comment: I realised this is your 3rd/4th question All good. Keep trying to get better :) Go over the [FAQ]'s, check formatting of other questions and try and articulate your question as if you were reading it for the first time. Good luck!

Comment: How can i include the database table in my question.

Comment: A screenshot? or mock up data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
Dim myField As Variant   'IMPORTANT

myField = Application.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)

If IsError(myField) Then
    MsgBox "no match is found in range(" & rngToSearch.Address & ")."
Else
    'Filter Data
    DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch1 & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="=*" & mySearch2 & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="=*" & mySearch3 & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
End If
```

Comment: Thanx for replying Paul.. But after editing  it's showing run time error.. "Type Mismatch"..

Comment: You need to change `Dim myField As Variant` for this to work

Comment: Paul, now i am getting "ERROR 2042" when i debug it line by line.

Comment: Akshay, Error 2042 (#N/A) is the error returned by the Match function when it can't find the value you are looking for. It is supposed to work like that, and that's why was important for you to define `myField As Variant` because it has to be able to hold either a number (the index of the found value in the array), or the #N/A error. If `myField` contains Error 2042 it is properly detected by the `IsError()` check

Comment: Paul, you are right.. I already figured it out and changed  the data type with variant. Again thanx for clarifying it..

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating the expression instead:

```
If Evaluate("ISERROR(MATCH(""" & ButtonName & """," & Selection.Rows(1).Address & ",0))") Then
```