# Index match to retrieve based on contains VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am getting an error 1004 "Unable to get the Match property of the WorkSheet function class.
Any ideas?

```
Sub helper()
Dim k As Long

For k = 20 To 49
If Cells(k, 4).Value Like "*Opportunity*" Then

Cells(k, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("W20:W49"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(k, 22).Value, Range("D20:D49"), 0))

ElseIf Cells(k, 4) <> "" Then
    Cells(k, 5).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(IF(RC[-1]>1,VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Data Extract'!C1:C33,2,FALSE),""""),"""")"
    Else
''
End If

Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: You get this error if there is no match of the specified value. In your case Cells(K,22)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Match function error (Unable to get match property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268181/excel-vba-match-function-error-unable-to-get-match-property)

Comment: Replace `WorksheetFunction.` with `Application.`. Also, be consistent when using a formula: make it completely `R1C1`- or completely `A1`-style.

Comment: Also it's good practice to be explicit about what worksheets you're working with - is everything really on the same worksheet?

Comment: I noticed that the index match is working only if for example D23 and V23 = Opportunity , if it's like D23 and V24=Opportunity it throws the error. Therefore I have added option explicit and replaced worksheetfunction with Application as recommended by Vbasic2008 and also replaced Cells(k,22) with Range("V20:V49") but i still don't get exact match

Comment: Eliminate leading and trailing spaces like this `WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(Cells(k, 22).Value), Trim(Range("D20:D49")), 0)`. Or if the values are numbers check that not stored as string and numbers mixed in the cells.